# Mysql replace LIKE with MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query i am trying to optimize, I want to replace LIKE that is causing full table scan by a MATCH AGAIN command.

This is the original query, it is working great but too slow

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, (CASE WHEN a.title LIKE :keywords THEN 300 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN a.title LIKE :word_0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN a.description LIKE :word_0 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN cl.name LIKE :word_0 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN cpl.name LIKE :word_0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN cl.description LIKE :word_0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN cpl.description LIKE :word_0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as relevance,
FROM lara237posts as a
INNER JOIN lara237categories as c ON c.id=a.category_id AND c.active=1
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cp ON cp.id=c.parent_id AND cp.active=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, post_id FROM lara237payments WHERE active=1 GROUP BY post_id) mpy ON mpy.post_id = a.id AND a.featured=1
LEFT JOIN lara237payments as py ON py.id=mpy.max_id
LEFT JOIN lara237packages as p ON p.id=py.package_id
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cl ON cl.translation_of=c.id AND cl.translation_lang = :translationLang
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cpl ON cpl.translation_of=cp.id AND cpl.translation_lang = :translationLang
WHERE a.country_code = :countryCode AND (a.verified_email = 1 AND a.verified_phone = 1) AND a.archived != 1 AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.reviewed = 1
GROUP BY a.id, relevance
HAVING relevance >= :average
ORDER BY p.lft DESC, relevance DESC, a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

I have create the query below to replace Like by MATCH AGAIN, but the second query is giving me no result. I am wondering where the issue is ?
Below is the second query i have created

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, (CASE WHEN MATCH(a.title, a.description) AGAINST(:keywords IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) THEN 300 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN MATCH(cl.name) AGAINST(:word_0 IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN MATCH(cpl.name) AGAINST(:word_0 IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN MATCH(cl.description) AGAINST(:word_0 IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN MATCH(cpl.description) AGAINST(:word_0 IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as relevance, py.package_id as py_package_id
FROM lara237posts as a
INNER JOIN lara237categories as c ON c.id=a.category_id AND c.active=1
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cp ON cp.id=c.parent_id AND cp.active=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, post_id FROM lara237payments WHERE active=1 GROUP BY post_id) mpy ON mpy.post_id = a.id AND a.featured=1
LEFT JOIN lara237payments as py ON py.id=mpy.max_id
LEFT JOIN lara237packages as p ON p.id=py.package_id
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cl ON cl.translation_of=c.id AND cl.translation_lang = :translationLang
LEFT JOIN lara237categories as cpl ON cpl.translation_of=cp.id AND cpl.translation_lang = :translationLang
WHERE a.country_code = :countryCode AND (a.verified_email = 1 AND a.verified_phone = 1) AND a.archived != 1 AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND a.reviewed = 1
GROUP BY a.id, relevance
HAVING relevance >= :average
ORDER BY p.lft DESC, relevance DESC, a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: How do you know `like` is causing the full table scan? Do you have an explain plan for the first query? (Add the explain plan into the question.)

Comment: `select distinct` is redundant if using and `group by` in a single query. You are ordering by `p.lft DESC` but this is not showing in the select clause

Comment: @Used_By_Already actually `SELECT DISTINCT a.*,  ..  GROUP BY a.id, relevance` is complete invalid ANSI SQL which shoudn't even execute.. But MySQL has extended GROUP BY feature which does execute at the cost of invalid/unrelated data for the non aggregate columns in the SELECTclause which are not in the GROUP BY clause.. Never MySQL version to respect ANSI SQL better because of the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql_mode... Topicstarter might be lucky when MySQL is using [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct data.

Comment: Raymond, it will execute in MYSQL unless ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY has been enabled. It is (imho) very poor that MySQL ever allowed this into the wild, and it even used to be the default setting to allow this crappy query syntax. This is slowly being changed but not before a generation of MySQL user actually think group by this way is normal... sigh

Comment: "it will execute in MYSQL unless ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY has been enabled" @Used_By_Already i know sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY yes and functional dependency for that matter i indeed didn't  mention it should be enabled.. "This is slowly being changed but before a generation of MySQL user actually think group by this way is normal" You are right 9 out 10 question/answers about MySQL on stackoverflow which are using GROUP BY are plain wrong..

Comment: so what do you propose to fix this query?